# Drag event listener on div

Tags: javascript, html, css, draggable

**How can use the drag event for a div while the photo and the link inside have `dragging: false` attribute?**

If we add the `draggable: true` attribute to the div, when we drag, the dragged content will move with the mouse.
Is it possible to make the drag event work and the dragged content does not appear on the screen after dragging?

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div")
div.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
  console.log("it works")
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img draggable="false" src="https://4my3boyz.com/content/images/thumbs/0012369_landscape-medley-blue-sky-with-white-clouds-cotton-fabric_500.jpeg">
  <a draggable="false" href="#">Blue Sky</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault).

Remove the `draggable="false"` attribute from your elements, then in your event listener prevent the default behaviour of dragging like this:

```
const div = document.querySelector("div")

div.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  console.log("it works")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use the draggable attribute on the div itself

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div")
div.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
  console.log("it works");
  div.style.border="solid"
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: blue;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div draggable="true">
  <img draggable="false" src="https://4my3boyz.com/content/images/thumbs/0012369_landscape-medley-blue-sky-with-white-clouds-cotton-fabric_500.jpeg">
  <a draggable="false" href="#">Blue Sky</a>
</div>
```

Comment: For me the dragged content is still visible.

Comment: ?? what do you mean, still visible ? However , if you drag the div, all of its content follows , is this what bothers you ? @tsgrgo

Comment: Yes, when you drag the div. I think the asker wanted so there is nothing moving with the mouse.

Comment: Yes, I designed a draggable slider. But when I dragged on the slide, the content was also dragged.

Comment: Oki, i understand now